# Using Makefile to selectively simulate a test

Tags: makefile, compilation, simulate

I would like a Makefile variable to hold a list of tests but run each test with a different flag and have the ability to run all tests or selectively one from the command line. Here's what I have so far and I am not sure how to add more tests but prevent creating individual variables for each test. In the example below I can say make all or make run_tests TESTS=block_test_A to either run all tests or a specific test. This works but if I were to add another 10 tests I would like to modify only TESTS string and add them there instead of adding TEST4, TEST5 and so on. Is there a clever way to make a loop that can parse the list of tests in TESTS and create the variables. I tried a couple of variations but couldnt get it to work. sim_design is target not shown that will execute the compile/sim using the values in the Makefile variables SIM_FLAGS and SIM_LOG. Thanks.

```
TESTS := block_test_A block_test_B block_test_C

TEST1 := $(word 1, $(TESTS))
$(TEST1) :  SIM_FLAGS:= "$(SIM_FLAGS) -top $(TEST1)"
$(TEST1) :  SIM_LOG:= "logs/$(TEST1).log"

TEST2 := $(word 2, $(TESTS))
$(TEST2) :  SIM_FLAGS:= "$(SIM_FLAGS) -top $(TEST2)" 
$(TEST2) :  SIM_LOG:= "logs/$(TEST2).log"

TEST3 := $(word 3, $(TESTS))
$(TEST3) :  SIM_FLAGS:= "$(SIM_FLAGS) -top $(TEST3)" 
$(TEST3) :  SIM_LOG:= "logs/$(TEST3).log"

$(TESTS):
    $(shell mkdir -p logs)
    @(echo Running TEST $@ with SIM_FLAGS=$(SIM_FLAGS) SIM_LOG=$(SIM_LOG))
    $(MAKE) sim_design SIM_FLAGS=$(SIM_FLAGS) SIM_LOG=$(SIM_LOG)

run_tests: $(TESTS)

all:
    @(echo Running Regression on $(DESIGN_TOP) with following list of tests $(TESTS))
    @(echo To run a single test generating a dump use: make run_tests TESTS=\"valid_test_name\" REGRESS=0)
    $(MAKE) run_tests REGRESS=1
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like exactly what [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) were created for...?

What's wrong with this:

```
TESTS := block_test_A block_test_B block_test_C

SIM_FLAGS += -top $@
SIM_LOG = logs/$@.log

$(TESTS):
        @mkdir -p logs
        @echo Running TEST $@ with SIM_FLAGS=$(SIM_FLAGS) SIM_LOG=$(SIM_LOG)
        $(MAKE) sim_design SIM_FLAGS="$(SIM_FLAGS)" SIM_LOG="$(SIM_LOG)"
```

Other things:

- You never want to use the make `shell` function inside a recipe.
- I don't really see the point in putting `echo` into a subshell with `(...)`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I had messed up when I used automatic variables and wasn't knowledgeable enough to debug the issue. Your example helps me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: The trick is you can't use simple variables (`:=`) when you want to put automatic variables in the value, since you need to defer expansion until they're actually in the recipe.